# Difference between jQuery wrap and wrapAll

Tags: jquery

What's the difference between jQuery .wrap and .wrapAll? They pretty much do the same thing, but what could be the difference?

Comment: If you're smart enough to write, you're probably smart enough to read. Here you go: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/ http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/

Comment: just even rather keen

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Notice the difference in the descriptions:

> [**`.wrap()`**](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/): Wrap an HTML structure around **each** element in the set of matched elements.
>   [**`.wrapAll()`**](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/): Wrap an HTML structure around **all** elements in the set of matched elements.

`.wrap()` wraps every element individually, but `.wrapAll()` wraps all of them as a group.

For example:

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
```

With `$('.foo').wrap('<div class="bar" />');`, this happens:

```
<div class="bar"><div class="foo"></div></div>
<div class="bar"><div class="foo"></div></div>
<div class="bar"><div class="foo"></div></div>
```

But with `$('.foo').wrapAll('<div class="bar" />');`, this happens:

```
<div class="bar">
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="foo"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

WrapAll wraps ALL elements, Wrap wraps EACH element.

```
$('.inner').wrapAll('<div class="new" />');
```

Results in wrapping **ALL** inner-divs in one new div

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="new">
    <div class="inner">Hello</div>
    <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Wrap results in ... **EACH** element

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="new">
    <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="new">
    <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Adding jquery to execute a wrap:

$(‘p’).wrap(‘<span class=”newclass” />’);

will result in:

<span class=”newclass”>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</span>

<span class=”newclass”>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</span>

<span class=”newclass”>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</span>



Substitute the .wrap for .wrapAll.

$(‘p’).wrapAll(‘<span class=”newclass” />’);

will result in:

<span class=”newclass”>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</span>



Now try out .wrapInner.

$(‘p’).wrapInner(‘<span class=”newclass” />’);

will result in:

<p><span class=”newclass”>This is a paragraph.</span></p>
<p><span class=”newclass”>This is a paragraph.</span></p>
<p><span class=”newclass”>This is a paragraph.</span></p>
```